# Is there another way to make a screenshot of background windows apart from screencapture -l?

Tags: macos, bash, background, applescript

I'd like to take a screenshot of a background window given its title.

I know this can be made with `screencapture -l idwindow output` but unluckily I can't use this method because I'm on a Mac OS X 10.5.8 system so the command screencapture doesn't support the option -l.

Are there other ways to achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you want to do this within a shell script?

Comment: yes, or something that I can launch from there :)

Comment: Here are some suggestions: http://superuser.com/questions/164892/screen-capture-command-line

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm checking them out but I'm afraid they won't work for a background screenshot.

Comment: It's like they provide scripts to record the screen not to take a screenshot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667214/screencapture-l-illegal-option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GrabFS`](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103164014/https://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter11/grabfs/) looks like a nifty tool that can solve your problem. It basically turns running programs into a file system like structure that lets you grab screenshots of those running programs.

Requires Mac OS X Leopard and [MacFUSE](https://code.google.com/archive/p/macfuse). You are on 10.5.8 (Leopard?) so that should work out OK.